# How do I tell which items I've bought from a store?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2

Stores in Xenoblade 2 offer [Store Deeds](https://xenoblade.fandom.com/wiki/Store_Deed) after you've purchased one of every other item in a store. When I see that I have 0 of an item, I often can't remember if I've never bought the item before or if I've just used up my supply.

Is there a way to tell which items you've previously purchased from a store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to I be a way to check which items you've purchased already. I ended up buying every item I didn't already have at stores I didn't own the deed to.